# Cannot open SQL Server 2008 database in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with SQL Server 2008. Whenever I am trying to connect to database I get an error. I am using c# language. As I am new to .net development I can not understand what to do. Please help me to get rid of this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
string str, constr;
Boolean inc = false;
SqlDataReader dr;
constr = "Server = JITSEKHAR-PC ; Database = Hospitaldata ; user id = ; password = ; Integrated Security = True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
con.Open();
```

Here is the complete error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
>   Message="Cannot open database \"Hospitaldata\" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Jitsekhar-PC\Jitsekhar'."
>   Source=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"
>   ErrorCode=-2146232060
>   Class=11
>   LineNumber=65536
>   Number=4060
>   Procedure=""
>   Server="JITSEKHAR-PC"
>   State=1

Comment: Are you trying to connect via Windows Authentication of SQL Server Authentication? The user id and password in the connection string should be for SQL server accounts, not windows accounts.

Comment: i am using windows authentication and i have left the username and password field blank during establishing database connection that's why i also left the user id and password field blank in the constr.

Answer (score 2):

If you have **both** `User Id=..;Password=....` as well as `Integrated Security=True` in your connection string, then the `Integrated Security` part wins and SQL Server is trying to use your **Windows account** to log on - and obviously from the error message, that's not possible.

Change your connection string to be:

```
constr = "Server=JITSEKHAR-PC;Database=Hospitaldata;user id=.....;password=.....";
```

**NOW** your defined `user id=` and password will be used and you should be OK to log in.

Comment: can i use integrated security = SSPI in case of windows authentication?does it generate any error?

Comment: @Sukanta: if you have an account in SQL Server for your Windows user - then yes, you can use integrated security to connect to that SQL Server instance. It's the preferred and recommended way of connecting to SQL Server, if available.